# Representing a sentence in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

How to represent the following sentence in FOL ( First Order Logic ) "There is an animal which only eats meat" 
 Is the following represantaion true ? 
Ǝx Eats(x, meat) where x is animal

Comment: No, your logic says "There is an animal which eats meat". Your logic does not say that the animal *only* eats meat.

Comment: So what about this? Ǝx∀y Animal(x) AND Food(y) --> Eats(x, y) { y: Meat)

Answer (score 0):

One minor correction would make it corrrect. It would look a little silly though.
Make Eats into OnlyEats.

Comment: I dunno, the word "only" in the English sentence seems to be missing from the FOL sentence.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not entirely correct. As pointed out in the comments by Gabe, your expression does not exclude the possibility of x eating other things as well. You'll need to add a conjunct that excludes all foodstuffs that aren't meat. How you do this depends a bit on which kind of logic you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Could he just say:

-Eats(x, y) ^ y != meat

implying meat is the only thing the animal doesn't not eat?

Pretty pessimistic view, but it gets the job done, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a simple way to represent the sentence is:

> Ǝx∀y (Animal(x) ∧ Eats(x,y)) --> Meat(y)